# Memory Map for RTOS

Tags: embedded, rtos

I am looking forward to understand, what purpose a memory map serves in embedded system.
How does the function stack differs here, from normal unix system.

Any insights that can help me debug few memory related crashes for embedded system will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Embedded systems, especially real-time ones, often have a lot of statically-allocated data, and/or data placed at specific locations in memory. The memory map tells you where these things are, which can be helpful when you run into problems and need to examine the state of the system. For example, you might dump all of memory and then analyze it after the fact; in such a case, the memory map will be rather handy for finding the objects you suspect might be related to the problem.

On the code side, your system might log a hardware exception that points to the address of the instruction where the exception was detected. Looking up the memory locations of functions, combined with a disassembly of the function, can help you analyze such problems.

The details really depend on what kind of embedded system you're building. If you provide more details, people may be able to give better responses.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand the question.  You seem to be suggesting that a "memory map" is something unique to embedded systems or that it is a tangible software component. It is neither; it is merely a description of the layout of an application's memory usage.

All applications will have a memory map regardless of platform, the difference is that typically on an embedded system the application is linked as a single monolithic entity, so that the resultant memory layout refers to the entire system rather than an individual process as it might in an application on a GPOS platform.

It is the linker and the linker script that determines memory mapping, and your linker will be able to output a map report file that describes the layout and allocation applied.  This is true of embedded and desktop applications regardless of OS or architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The memory map for a RTOS is not that much different than the memory map for any computer.  It defines which hardware resides at which of the processor's addresses.  That hardware may be RAM, ROM, Flash, serial ports, parallel ports, timers, interrupt vectors, or any number of other parts addressable by the processor.

The memory map also describes how you intend to budget for limited resources such as RAM, ROM, or Flash in your system design.

For instance, if there's multiple tasks running, RAM might be mapped so that each task has it's own specific area of RAM allocated to it.

In turn, each tasks's part of RAM would be mapped so that there are specific areas for the stack, another for static variables, and perhaps more again for heap(s).

When you have an operating system on the target, it looks after a lot of this dynamically.  However, if your application is the only software on the device, you'll have to manage these decisions yourself, usually at compile/link time.  Search "link scripts" for further clues,

Answer (score 0):

The Memory map is a layout of memory of system. It is present in both embedded systems and normal applications. Though it is present in normal applications, it's usage is well appreciated in embedded systems due to system constraints.

Memory map is managed by means of linker scripts or linker command files. It maps resources like Flash or Internal RAM(L1P,L1D,L2,L3) or External RAM(DDR) or ROM or peripherals (ports,serial,parallel,USB etc) or specific device registers or I/O ports with appropriate fixed addresses in the memory space of the system.

In case of embedded systems, based on the memory configuration or constraints of board and performance requirements, the segments like text segment or data segment or BSS can also be placed in the appropriate memory of choice.

There are occasions where various versions of development boards will have different configurations of memory and peripherals. In that case, we may need to edit the linker scripts according to memory configuration and peripherals of the board as an essential check-point in board bring-up.

Memory map can help in defining the shared memory too that can play a key role in multi-threaded applications and also for multi-core applications.

Crashes can be debugged by back tracing the address of crash and mapping it to the memory of the system to get an high level idea of the possible library or object causing the problem.